# group by+where on calculated column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

```
SELECT
   SUM(a)-SUM(b) AS c1,
   SUM(a) AS c2,
   SUM(b) AS c3
FROM tbldoc
GROUP BY Cid 
WHERE c1<>0
```

If you take ( `WHERE c1<>0` )  not error

Thank you Answer

Comment: While this question has certainly been asked before, I don't agree with *which* question this has been marked a duplicate of. In particular, there is a lack of understanding as to when to apply the `where` clause and when to apply the `having` clause which is fundamental here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you mean that you get an error with this query, and that if you remove the where clause you get no error, but not the right answer.

You need a `having` clause, which is like `where` but can be applied to the aggregated results:

```
select
  sum(a)-sum(b) AS c1,
  sum(a) AS c2,
  sum(b) AS c3
from tbldoc
group by Cid
having sum(a)-sum(b) <> 0;
```

Alternatively, you can move the whole statement to a subquery and perform the where on the outside:

```
select *
from (
  select
    sum(a)-sum(b) AS c1,
    sum(a) AS c2,
    sum(b) AS c3
  from tbldoc
  group by Cid
) s
where c1 <> 0;
```