# SQL where clause effect on table?

Tags: syntax

I have sql query as

```
select sourceIP, sum(sourceBytes) 
from flows
group by sourceIP
order by sum(sourceBytes) desc
```

This brings result (dummy) as:-

```
sourceIp     SourceBytes
192.168.1.2  100
192.168.1.3  79
192.168.1.4  67
192.168.1.5  4
192.168.1.6  4
```

Now if I change the query to

```
select sourceIP, sum(sourceBytes) 
from flows
where sourceBytes > 50
group by sourceIP
order by sum(sourceBytes) desc
```

The output be

```
 sourceIp        SourceBytes
 192.168.1.2     150
 192.168.1.3     40
```

I don't have access to DB right now, I cannot pull /show real table values, but the point here I want to make with the `greater` then statement the output is changed. I was of the view with second query I just want to process the results instead of all the values present `flows` table to just values which are greater range i.e 50. I want to know what level these two queries are not the same. Thanks.

Comment: The second output looks impossible to me. How can `sum(x)` be less than `x` when `x` must be greater than 50?

Comment: I agree what was a typo, remember this table is not output of real cmd just what i was seeing on screen at my office, different results with different bytes size values.

Comment: That's what I thought. Basically, if I understand you correctly, you need `having` instead of `where`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [group by+where on calculated column](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66316/group-bywhere-on-calculated-column)

Comment: Colin, I don't agree this question is a dupe of the one you suggest.  However, your answer to that question is very likely the answer to this question.  Perhaps you could modify your answer to suit this question, and post it here?

Comment: I already did :-) Yes, question is different, answer the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing a `sum()` which means you "lose" the original values -- they are aggregated.

By applying a `where` clause, you filter rows *before* the aggregation phase.

I suspect what you want is a `having` clause, something like:

```
select sourceIP, sum(sourceBytes) 
from flows
group by sourceIP
having sum(sourceBytes) > 50 
order by sum(sourceBytes) desc;
```

`Having` is like a `where` but applied to the aggregated results.

Note that you can also use a subquery and a `where` instead of `having` as follows:

```
select * from (
  select sourceIP, sum(sourceBytes) as sum_sourceBytes 
  from flows
  group by sourceIP
) a
where sum_sourceBytes > 50
order by sum_sourceBytes desc;
```